# in postgres, editing pg_hba.conf didnt enable passwordless login

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.2.1 on Windows 10

postgres user -- not able to log into psql (I forgot my password)

I changed the postgres user password in Windows (I don't know if this makes a difference, but pg_ctl still starts)

I added the line to `PostgreSQL\data\pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all    all    127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

(changed "md5" to "trust" to not require password)

```
pg_ctl -D data stop
pg_ctl -D data start
("server starting")

psql -U postgres
```

(asks for password anyway)
I want to be able to log in without a password, change the password, then reconfigure to require password again, but haven't successfully enabled password-less login despite doing what the popular answer said to do)

Comment: Try with 0.0.0.0/0 instead of 127.0.0.1/32 or local all all trust

Comment: Does `psql -h localhost -U postgres` work?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

1. `localhost` is resolved to the IPv6 address `::1` on your machine.

   You should change the line for `::1` too.
2. You added the line to the end of the file, but there is an earlier entry that matches your host, user and database name.

   Try to add the line in the begining of the file.

Moreover, you **really** shouldn't be running 9.2.1. Not only is it out of support, but it suffers from CVE-2013-1899 which allows any attacker with network access to destroy your database server.

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced this issue with PostgreSQL 15. In the end I just altered the method for each existing line to trust:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

This allowed me to log in to the postgres user and alter the password via a SQL statement; I then reverted the config changes immediately afterwards.

No idea why adding a line at the top of the file doesn't work.